# Parsing JSON object with Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to read from a Uri which i created and to display it on windows phone 7 app.
(I'm doing this tutorial:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/Video/hh237494).

My problem is that the program doesnt get into the OpenReadCompletedEventHandler and i dont know why. (i putted message box in order to debug and i found out that the program doesnt get into the OpenReadCompletedEventHandler). Here is the relevant code:

```
    void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:44705/Service1.svc/GetAllBrands");
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
            try
            {
                webClient.OpenWriteAsync(uri);
                MessageBox.Show("opening sucsseded");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OpenRead Handler");

      //  OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs temp = (OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs)e;
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = null;
        try
        {
            serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Brand>));
            ObservableCollection<Brand> Brands = serializer.ReadObject(e.Result) as ObservableCollection<Brand>;
            foreach (Brand b in Brands)
            {
                int id = b.BrandId;
                string name = b.BrandName;
                listBrands.Items.Add(id + "             " + name);

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used this but a quick google takes me to this page on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openreadcompleted.aspx

This should tell you why it's not working - because you are using a read event for a write operation. You should be using `OpenWriteCompletedEventHandler` with `OpenWriteAsync` as per this page on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openwritecompleted.aspx